# How can I obtain an official English-Slovak translation?

Tags: trains, slovakia

EU students receive zero-fare travel with the Slovakian State Railways, but [the page on zero-fare travel](http://www.slovakrail.sk/en/zero-fare.html) states:

> Students are required to submit confirmation of enrolment for the
>   current  academic year together with an **official translation to Slovak
>   language** ( for documents in Czech language translations are not
>   necessary) and an ID document (+ profile picture)

How likely are they to enfore the translation requirement, and is there any more sensible way of obtaining a translation than googling "Official Translation Bratislava", and using one of the (often poorly located) agencies that crop up?

I see that there is a [Slovak-language form](http://www.slovakrail.sk/fileadmin/dokumenty/2017_pdf/33628_Ziadanka_na_vydanie_preukazu_07_17.pdf) which domestic students are required to fill out, could I use this (with the help of Google Translate and a willing university official)?

Comment: My experience with Google translate is that it does not come up to the standard of an official translation especially for less commonly spoken languages.

Comment: @mdewey, absolutely, but it's plenty good enough to work out what the fields on the form mean and fill it out correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Generally the requirement for an 'official translation' means a translation done by a certified translator (i.e. someone with a proper certification/qualification from the government of the country in question).

Your university might be able to help, for example if they regularly have Slovakian students who need their documents translated into English?

Comment: In some cases, it can be a notarized translation too. You can translate it yourself and put a statement at the bottom that the translator is competent and the translation is accurate and complete and sign that statement in front of a notary public.

Comment: The various agencies' websites mention that there's a specific seal needed for an "official" translation, so I don't think it's that simple - it's so much easier in Polond where an ISIC card suffices as proof of student status.

Comment: @jacoman891, your profile says you're in Nottingham. Have you tried the university? They have enough [Slovak students](http://nottingham.ac.uk/studywithus/international-applicants/country-info/countryinformation/slovakia.aspx) to have a student group with a Facebook page. Maybe someone there can put you in touch with a certified translator.